# Issue on zend dispatch loop

Tags: php, zend-framework, view, dispatch

I'm using Zend Framework to build a website and I'm having some trouble with the dispatch loop.

Normally, Zend Framework URLs are built this way: http://www.domain.com/module/controller/action.

On my website, I'm using customized dynamic URLs which are parsed on the dispatch loop by a custom method. So, each one of these URLs, after being parsed, will execute a specific action of a specific controller and module.

I need to perform some tasks which depend on the module, controller and action that were parsed. The problem is that I'm only being able to know the parsed module, controller and action when dispatchLoopShutdown occurs. The tasks that I need to execute will set some cookies which will make changes on the output that will be sent to the browser.

But, at this point, the view has already been rendered, and the cookies that were set when dispatchLoopShutdown occurs won't change the output accordingly.

So, my question is... is there a way to force the view to be rendered again? Or a way to know what module, controller and action will be executed, before the dispatchLoopShutdown? I've also tried to accomplish this on the postDispatch but the results are the same!

Hope I could explain my problem right.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you might want to consider using http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html

Comment: With controller router I need to set some rules to match the requested URLs. I would have to create a catch-all rule and parse them all...

Comment: Before dispatchLoopShutdown, postDispatch is executed. Did you consider using writing a controller plugin that would be executed after dispatching an individual action (i.e. writing postDispatch method in the plugin).

Comment: I've tried to write postDispatch method but it executes my tasks once per loop iteration. I need the tasks to be executed only at the last iteration, that is where I know what is the final parsed action.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good schema about the Zend Framework sequence.

You can know the module, controller and action before the dispatch by using a controller plugin:

```
<?php
class Custom_Controller_Plugin_CheckRoute extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch($request)
    {
        //Get Request
        $controller = $request->controller;
        $action     = $request->action;
        $module     = $request->module; 

        //=> perform actions before dispatch

        //Update the Request
        $request->setModuleName('default')
            ->setControllerName('index')
            ->setActionName('action2');
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was solved by Zend_Controller_Plugin_ActionStack. I added some action where implemented logic from dispatchLoopShutdown. This link can be useful http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.plugins.html#zend.controller.plugins.standard.actionstack